# Google maps API: get lat / long separately

Tags: javascript, google-maps

After sending a `geocode` request and receiving a response with status **OK**, you can use `results[0].geometry.location` to retrieve both *latitude* and *longitude*.

But how do you get the lat / long **separately**? I can't find the right call in the [Google maps API reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `location` field is an object of type [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng).  To get the latitude, call it's `lat()` method.  To get the longitude, call it's `lng()` method.

For example:

```
var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
```

Comment: Yup, that's it!

Answer (score 1):

`results[0].geometry.location` is a [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) object, it has a `.lat()` method that returns the latitude and a `.lng()` method that returns the longitude.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="pac-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
<div id="map"></div>

<script>

function initMap(){

var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {

    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
    var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();

});

});

</script>
```